# saveHTML() not working properly

Tags: php, dom, include, php-include

I have this line of code in my index.php:

```
<?php include ("header.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

My header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php include("php/dynamic_header.php"); ?>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Write a description" /> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="Your keywords here" /> 
    <title>Random Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>This is my header</header>
```

And my dynamic_header.php:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile("header.php");

$meta = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta')->item(1);
$meta->setAttribute('content','new description');
$dom->saveHTML();
```

However, when I use saveHTML(), nothing happens.
I tried using:

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

But this produces two headers, so can someone explain me what am I doing wrong?
Basically, I'm trying to change attribute on my meta tag with PHP DOM, but I can't save it without duplicating my header.

Comment: Looks fine to me https://eval.in/107755

Comment: @Prix I see you added DATA, I'm not familiar with that, what does it do?

I tried your solution, but no changes, and now the header doesn't even show up.

Comment: [It's called **heredoc** and to put it simple its just a different way to declare a variable with several lines.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) The only difference between my code and yours is that mine is on a variable and yours is reading from a file, so perhaps you don't have the right permission to write back to the PHP file which is why its not saving it?

Comment: @Prix I did a bit of testing and researching and I found out that I need to use saveHTMLFile() in order to work. This also generated few unplanned bugs, so I changed my approach.

I think the problem is that my code is hand-coded in HTML, therefore read directly from a file, and without overwriting the original file no changes are possible, unless I want to delete the duplicated elements.

Your comment led me to the workaround, so submit an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work just as good with `saveHTMLFile()` which is why I believed something was wrong with your file permissions or so not allowing you to save back the data. Either way, I think you're doing this wrong you should use a template library instead of modifying the data with DOMDocument.

For example with [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), you could do a header template like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="{$description|default:"Write a description"}" /> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="Your keywords here" /> 
    <title>{$title|default:"Default Page Title"}</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Here was the relevant test code to show it would not create duplicates with DOMDocument:

```
<?php
$str = <<<DATA
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php include("php/dynamic_header.php"); ?>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Write a description" /> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="Your keywords here" /> 
    <title>Random Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>This is my header</header>
DATA;

$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($str);
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhitespace = false;

$meta = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta')->item(1);
$meta->setAttribute('content','new description');
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```